# PyGTK menu doesn't display under Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: python, pygtk, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-11.10, pygui

I have a PyGTK application, and it works fine in Gnome, but under Unity (ubuntu 10.10+) the global menu bar doesn't work - the menus are not displayed in the application window *or* the top bar. Is there a way to force the menu to either skip the global menu bar or display in it?

**Edit:**
Minimal sample added.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import GUI
from GUI import Window

app = GUI.Application()

window = Window()

window.show()

app.run()
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to make any change to your application. Are you getting some kind of error and/or warning? Do you have some piece of code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. I do not know what code specifically is causing it as I am using a library (PyGUI) which wraps PyGTK.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example which shows this problem and post it here? I don't know if you're going to find an answer otherwise, because I don't think PyGUI is very popular and PyGTK in general does work with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with simple programs created using pygtk. I believe the situation is:

- pygtk works with gtk2.x
- Unity uses gtk3
- pygtk does not work with gtk3
- python-gobject is the gtk3 equivalent of pygtk

You have an extra layer of complexity since you're using pyGUI. Most likely, pyGUI uses pygtk, which will not work with GTK3 / Unity. You can either persuade the people at pyGUI to release a GTK3-compatible version, or re-write your app from scratch using python-gobject.

Comment: Neither one of which is particularly appealing, but dropping PyGUI would break cross-platform compatibility. Thanks for your help.